# How to build wireshark like tool

Tags: networking

What level of networking knowledge would be required to build something like wireshark? What is the route that I would take to approach this? I don't know much about networking, and everyone that I know tells me some thing about CCNA or CISCO, would taking these courses allow me to build tools like wireshark? If not which route should be taken to be self taught to this level?

Comment: This is too broad to answer as it is. To create a program, you will need to understand some sort programming language To make something similar is a combination of a lot of things - you need to know how networking works, how packet transfer itself over the network, how to capture the packet, how to read and interpret the packet content. The simplest starting point would be to make a program that all it does is "listen" on a port (and simply spit out any packet received), and then create another program (or use existing one) to connect and send information there. That is the bare minimum.

Comment: @Darius , I know how to do the bare minimum with python, but, don't know how to advance, Is this CISCO or CCNA course gonna teach me such stuff?

Comment: Looking through the source code of WireShark will familiarise you with what's needed. It's available on [GitHub](https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark). Advice on how to acquire such knowledge is beyond the scope of this forum.

Comment: @mathmaniage, no. It will teach you network engineering, specifically Cisco's flavor of net engineering. check out codeacademy.com, they have free online courses if you would like to advance in Python, html, css, Ruby on rails, php, etc etc etc. The CCNA is the fundamental cert for networking.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart , So, what do you call the coding part of networking? Any course for those? Any certificaitions for those? I suppose they're both different right?

Comment: @mathmaniage, by coding do you mean the CLI? (Command line interface)

Comment: @Tim_Stewart, no, I mean developing a new concept, like someone developed ad_hoc networking , I want to have knowledge to do something like that

Comment: This would require many different disciplines. Two people separately were working on ad-hoc in the early 90's. I believe it was then turned over to the IETF (internet engineering task force) for rfc's (request for comments) later I believe it was assigned to a working group. (A whole group of engineers and programmers)

Comment: You would not only need to have a intimate knowledge of networking, but also expert level programming, as you would most likely be tearing down drivers and re-writing them. (Something has to interface with the standards based hardware!)

Comment: This in no way should be taken as discouragement. I wish you the best of luck on the learning journey ahead!

Comment: @Tim_Stewart ,  Okay, but my question is, people become network engineers, taking CCNA and CCNP s and go on like that to hit 6 figure salary, but would these people who reach this 6 figure stage, have the potential knowledge to build such a thing? like the ad-hoc networking?

Comment: This is my personal opinion. So, take it or leave it. Cisco is a specialized version of networking. (Alot of it is still Cisco proprietary) you will be a network specialist after CCNP level, try the ICND1&ICND2... If you don't like the learning material or tests, this isn't the career choice for you. 1. Don't go into networking because of money, you WILL be forced to continually learn industry technologies that will become like nails on a chalkboard if you don't enjoy learning it.. 2. The Cisco certifications are useful, but in my area CCNA = 40-50k ccnp = 60-75k.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could divide it into at least these main topics:

1. How to collect packets from the OS – knowledge of features provided by the operating system's network stack (and occassionally driver model).

   For example, Wireshark relies on libpcap to do the heavy lifting, which itself needs to know about capture methods on Linux, on BSDs, and comes with its own kernel driver for Windows (i.e. WinPcap/Npcap).
2. How to interpret packets' contents – knowledge of where to find information about various networking protocols.

   Primarily this involves decoding binary data, as Wireshark doesn't actually *participate* in any of those protocols; it leaves final interpretation to the user.
3. How to present the data (and the program's other features) in an understandable way – user interface design is a whole separate topic from programming or networking, but quite an important one.

   (It might cause exceptions to the 2nd point – for example, Wireshark *does* understand TCP connections in order to provide various convenience features such as "Follow stream").
4. How to implement the user interface you've designed ­– general programming; knowledge of the GUI toolkit used by the OS (for example, Wireshark recently migrated from GTK to Qt).